# Server side Blazor Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-3.0

How do I set the HttpContext.User from a razor login page in my server side Blazor app?

The user credentials are fetched from Active Directory when the user signs in. The reason for the login page is that I want to allow people to sign in from outside of the domain (if the ar at a client or similar).

Or don I use something else than HttpContext.User in Blazor?

Comment: As far as I can tell, authentication in Blazor isn't fully supported at the moment. There are ways of making it work, but they aren't fully 100% supported. During episode 27 of The .NET Core Podcast (disclosure: I'm the host), Chris Sainty said (referring to .NET Core 3.0, "There's going to be an authentications coming in that one which I think is something that's been anticipated by the community for quite a long time. We've kind of been able to do authentication but it's been not been anything over the official. But with version six we're getting at that, which is awesome"

Comment: @Jamie Taylor, I think that authentication in Blazor server-side is fully supported, though updates are inevitable.

Comment: @Issac Ok. I was going off of what Chris had said, but couldn't remember whether he was referring to client-side or server-side Blazor.

Comment: @Jamie Taylor, Authentication I dare say is fully supported in client-side Blazor too. Perhaps not complete, but still supported. See the following how to implement authentication on Blazor client-side: https://github.com/dotnet-presentations/blazor-workshop/blob/1c35728a9cafb1add72e14fae88dd037216913d7/docs/06-authentication-and-authorization.md

Comment: @Fred, please focus on a single question. Where do you want to set your HttpContext.User ? Are you using the Blazor built-in authentication objects ?

Comment: @jamie Thank you! I am a subscriber. I will look in to the link provided.

Comment: @issac Thank you! Maybe I asked the question in the wrong way. What I am trying to find out is how do I manually authenticate the user in server side Blazor? I tried with HttpContext.SignInAsync but it responds with "Response already started".

Comment: Would something like this implementation help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57172840/how-do-you-create-a-api-identityserver-blazorserver-side-application